# How to apply changes from old branch to master, if master now is broken?

Tags: git

I have two branches - broken `master` and `normal_state` with an old working code.

Master was broken by merge commit and other severals so, I can't revert those dozens of commits. I need apply my state from `normal_state` to `master`. And make it in the way where `normal_state` will be write above changes of `master`. How to do that?

Comment: This sounds like a series of hacks.  If `master` be broken, and `normal_state` is in good condition, then why not just work with the latter branch?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the remote version of `master` branch (I mean if you either are alone on the repo, or have explicitly agreed with the other users), make a backup of the current state of `master` for further debugging, and reset it where `normal_state` is :

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b backup_master
git branch -f master normal_state
git push -f origin master
```

You'll then be able to work on `backup_master` to clean up the mess if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to apply the commits in your `normal_state` on top of `master`. You will probably get to solve some merge-conflicts.

`git rebase master normal_state`